# Specify file name with curl --upload-file

Tags: command-line, filenames, rename, curl

When uploading a file with `curl`'s `--upload-file` option, how do I specify a file name different than the one on disk? With the `-F` option, it can be done like this, I think: `curl -F 'file=@/path/to/file/badname;filename=goodname'`, but I'm not sure how to do the equivalent with `--upload-file` (also `-T`). I am using an API which requires an uploaded file to have a certain filename, but I don't want to copy the file on-disk just so I can upload it properly.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
curl URL>/goodname --upload-file badfilename
```

Example:

```
curl http://example.com/goodname.html --upload-file badfilename.html
```

I tried this and managed to upload a file called `goodname.html` :)

Answer (score 0):

curl -v --user 'username:password' --upload-file {path}/{binaire} {your_url}/{binaire}

Answer (score 0):

When you upload file using POST method and --form (-F) option, curl uses multipart/form-data content type:

```
POST /test.html HTTP/1.1
Host: example.org
Content-Type: multipart/form-data;boundary="boundary"

--boundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="field1"

value1
--boundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="field2"; filename="example.txt"

value2
--boundary--
```

As you can see, there is a place for filename. But when you use --upload-file (-T), curl will use PUT method and there will not be such place, because the body of the request will consist only of sole file body:

```
PUT /test.html HTTP/1.1
Host: example.org

file content
```

The only filename here is in URL itself: test.html

Answer (score -1):

Use curl’s `--url` option like this:

```
curl --upload-file /path/to/file/badname --url http://serverip/remotedir/goodname
```

Comment: This doesn't work

Comment: This doesn't look like a general purpose solution